# How to push and pop in a single page multiple times in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a product page in a flutter. on the product page I show some similar products. when the user navigates through similar products, I push the new page into the stack. when the user hits the back button and I pop the page, I expect it to go to the previous product but it seems like all the product pages are alike in the stack and after a pop, it goes back to the main page. How can I how to push and pop in a single page multiple times in flutter?

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

It's.. unexpected.

A stack works this way

```
Page 1

[Push Products Screen]

ProductsScreen <-on Top
Page 1

[Push similar products]

SimilarProductsScreen <-on Top
ProductsScreen
Page 1
```

You should call push() or pushNamed() like this`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Products.similar')` , and call pop like `Navigator.of(context).pop()` for it to behave this way. It would help if you posted some code